# How to set specific width and height while recording video and taking screenshots in oculus go

Tags: oculusgo

I am trying to record video using adb command for oculus go submission but unable to set height and width. I am trying following commands:

```
adb shell setprop debug.oculus.enableVideoCapture 1
adb shell setprop debug.oculus.videoResolution 1536
adb shell setprop debug.oculus.textureWidth 2560
adb shell setprop debug.oculus.textureHeight 1440
```

Also facing the same issue while taking screenshots, as per all documentation i found that oculus Go only support screenshot resolution 1024x1024 and while submission its asking me 2560x1440 px.  Is there any other way i can set values for video and screenshots?